# actionListener not getting Invoked upon "close re-open" of a window

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have a pop-up which opens when clicking the button `printName`. The `pop-up` has a  `check-box`. The `check-box` when `checked prints name` in the pop-up and when `unchecked clears name` from the pop-up.

The problem happens when the pop-up is `closed and reopened`. The checkbox irrespective of being default `checked` does not invoke the `actionListener`(does not print the name).

So now I am trying to invoke the `printMyName` function just as the pop-up is generated from the listener initialized for the pop-up `(printName)` button

`printName` pop-up structure -

```
public NameDisplayPanel
      (
         NameEvent                   name,
         NameDisplayPanelListener listener
      ) 
      {
        this.name     = name;
        this.listener = listener;

         //Some code
      }
```

Here is the code to invoke `printMyName` when the `check-box` is toggled -

```
      CB = new JCheckBox("Display Selected", false);
      CB.addActionListener(
              new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      if (((JCheckBox) e.getSource()).isSelected()) CB.setSelected(true);
                      else  CB.setSelected(false);
                      printMyName();
                  }
              }
      );

      CB.setSelected(true); //Checks the checkbox true everytime the window reopens

      // Trying to implement method to invoke printMyName everytime when NameDisplayPanel pop-up is created.
```

Any leads for how to implement that listener?

Answer (score 0):

> Sets the state of the button. Note that this method does not trigger an actionEvent. Call **doClick to perform a programmatic action change**.

[API Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected(boolean))